Why can't I execute commands in Linux terminal?
The framework I am using is .Net 8.
I tried to followed the accepted answer in How to execute Linux command line in C# Mono
And here is my code:
ProcessStartInfo _processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
_processStartInfo.FileName = "dmesg | grep tty";
_processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Process p = Process.Start(_processStartInfo );
var _result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
p.Close();

After I ran the code, it reports this error:
Unhandled exception. System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred           trying to start process 'dmesg | grep tty' with working directory '/home/admin'          . No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo,           String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCr          edentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32          & stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

In terminal of putty, the command runs well as below:

What's wrong with it?

Can you run this in a terminal directly? Where is the application currently running? The stacktrace seems to say you are trying that on a windows machine.

@TanveerBadar Yes, I can run it successfully in terminal directly. The application is currently running Avalonia (Linux DRM) in Rasbian Lite. I feel strange also that it reports an error about win32 while I never use this.

Try to use FileName and  Arguments like below, it works in my side.
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "/bin/bash",
    Arguments = "-c \"dmesg | grep tty\"",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true
};

Here is the test result in my azure app service linux plateform.


It works now! BTW, what is the -c truly used for?

Hi @Volfogg -c        If the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, they are            assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.
